# Chern classes of a torsion sheaf supported in dimension $0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, characteristic-classes, intersection-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth algebraic K3-surface, and let $0 \neq \mathcal{F} \in \operatorname{Coh}(X)$ be a sheaf supported in dimension $0$. Let $\omega \in \operatorname{Pic}(X) \otimes \mathbb{R}$ be an ample class, and let $\beta \in \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ be arbitrary. I want to verify the following claim by Bridgeland in *Stability conditions on K3 surfaces*:
$$c_1(\mathcal{F}) \cdot \beta - \operatorname{rk}(\mathcal F) - \frac 1  2 (c_1(\mathcal{F})^2 + c_2(\mathcal{F})) < 0$$
Clearly $\operatorname{rk}(\mathcal{F}) = 0$, and I think that $c_1(\mathcal  F) = 0$ as well, because the support is $0$-dimensional, but I'm not sure about the argument.

**Question 1:** Is $c_1(\mathcal F) = 0$ true, and how to see this?

If this is settled, then the claim reduces to
$$c_2(\mathcal F) > 0, $$
but I don't see any reason for this.

**Question 2:** Why does this hold?

Comment: Any sheaf supported in dimension 0 is an extension of structure sheaves of points, so its enough to prove the claim for these. And for these you can use Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch.

Comment: @Sasha Why do I have to reduce to structure sheaves of points to apply Grothendieck/Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch?

Comment: A general sheaf with a 0-dimensional support is supported on a singular scheme, and I am not sure I know a version of GRR that works for a morphism from a singular scheme.

Comment: @Sasha I thought it might work as follows: Classical Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch says $\chi(E)=\langle\operatorname{ch}(E) \cap \operatorname{td}(X), [X]\rangle$ for a locally free sheaf $E$. Both the Euler characteristic and the Chern character are additive over short exact sequences, so if $E$ is not locally free one can choose a locally free resolution, and conclude that the formula still holds for $E$ by additivity.